# How to write attached code block in a for loop

Tags: java, logical-operators

How do I write following code in a simple for loop:

```
int asInt = (valueAsBytes[3] & 0xFF)
                | ((valueAsBytes[2] & 0xFF) << 8)
                | ((valueAsBytes[1] & 0xFF) << 16)
                | ((valueAsBytes[0] & 0xFF) << 24);
```

Comment: Eran gave a correct answer, but I feel urged to throw in that I think ( personal opinion!) it would be premature optimization. That code is readable and if it works, I  do not see why you would want to replace it with a for-loop.

Comment: I just wanted to generalise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the array index decreases by 1 in each access to `valueAsBytes`, while the second operand of the shift operator increases by 8 :

```
int asInt = 0;
for (int i = valueAsBytes.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    asInt |= valueAsBytes[i] & 0xFF << (valueAsBytes.length-i)*8;
```

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest a different solution?

I think a loop doesn't add any "clarity" to this code. The real issue is that you are duplicating code like (valueAsBytes[i] & 0xFF) four times.
If at all, you could do something like:

```
int asInt = maskIndexedValueAndShiftBy(3, 0) | maskIndexedValueAndShiftBy(2, 8) | ...
```

with

```
private final int maskIndexedValueAndShiftBy(int index, int shifter) {
   return (valueAsBytes[index] & 0xFF) << shifter;
```

The loop just makes the whole computation harder to understand.